# Vertically center both Icon and span in a div

Tags: html, css

The structure is like this:

```css
css
.toolBarHolder {
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class='toolBarHolder'>
  <icon class='toolBarIcon'>near_me</icon>
  <span class='toolBarText'>lake area</span>
</div>
```

with this the `span` can be vertically centered, but the `icon` failed.
[image]

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: @xmastertje I just added a pic

Comment: You can try `.toolBarIcon { vertical-align: middle; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the properties `display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center;` to `.toolBarHolder`. There's no need to use line-height;

It would be like this:

```
css
.toolBarHolder {
  height: 42px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

P.D.: Since we're using `justify-content: center`, you will also have to set a width (div content is centered horizontally aswell).

Comment: If you want the icon above the text, just add `flex-direction:column;` @MotokoNanano